# React Native CLI project build issues with app center getting the following errors

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-app-center

FAIL **tests**/App-test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

```
/Users/runner/runners/2.168.2/work/1/s/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/views/assets/back-icon.png:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){�PNG


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs/index.tsx:13:3)
```